# Auto resize Silverlight 3 applications

Tags: silverlight, onresize

I've been trying to get a Silverlight 3 application to automatically resize when rows are added to datagrids.
I've tried 
[this example](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Tip-Resizing-the-Silverlight-object-from-the-Silverlight-application.aspx)
but I just get a `System.ExecutionEngineException` with a null inner exception. I think this is aimed at Silverlight 2 only.
Can anyone tell me how to do this in Silverlight 3?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've got this working with the following:

Add the following javascript to the page with your silverlight object:

```
 function ResizeObject(height) {
        var host = document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost");
        host.style.height = height + "px";
    }
```

Add the following to your silverlight codebehind:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
        this.yourRootElement.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(LayoutRoot_LayoutUpdated);
    }

    private void LayoutRoot_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ResizeObject", new object[] { this.yourRootElement.RenderSize.Height });
    }
```

Note that "ResizeObject" refers to the javascript function on your webpage.